# how to support multiple screen in an android app if it contain more than one XMl file

Tags: android, xml, screen-resolution

I am working on an app having multiple XML files.I modified manifest as

```
<supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens  android:normalScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Made layout folders for different different densities but only xml which I am copying on these folders are working. Other XMLs are still lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following folders on res  and copy same xml to each other.

Customize each xml file for each resolution

```
layout-sw320dp 
layout-sw480dp  
layout-sw600dp 
layout-sw720dp
```

sw means "smalles width"

```
layout-sw320dp - small phones.  - devices with width grater than 320 dp
layout-sw480dp - large phones   - devices with width grater than 480 dp
layout-sw600dp - 7inch tablets    - devices with width grater than 600 dp
layout-sw720dp - 10 inch tablets    - devices with width grater than 720 dp
```

Read this article https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I add these folders. Should I copy every single Xml into these?

Comment: Yes and change params for each one. 

For examle in 

xml layout-sw320dp    set some param 30dp
xml layout-sw480dp    set some param 60dp
and so on

And you dont need params in manafest file. Default it supported for every resolution

Comment: You can do it inside code. But it is recomended way and dont worry the by lots of files. Read doc i recomended